# VisualStudioCodeの日本語化

Tags: vscode

VisualStudioCodeを使用していて、別のフォルダーを開いたところ表示言語が日本語から英語に代わってしまいました。調べてその通りに操作しても日本語になりません。
調べたページのリンクです。https://www.javadrive.jp/vscode/install/index4.html
よろしければ上記リンクページに書かれている以外の方法でVisualStudioCodeを日本語にする方法を教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: OSは何をお使いでしょうか？　VSCodeのVersionは何でしょうか？

Comment: osはWindows11です。VScodeのversionは1.79.2でした。

Comment: コマンドパレット(Command Palette)を開き、Configure Display Languageをクリックすると一覧が表示されます。一覧の「日本語(ja)」が選択されていますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

[Japanese Language Pack for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-CEINTL.vscode-language-pack-ja) がインストールされて有効になっているのであれば、ふつう日本語で表示されるはずです。VS Code を開き直すだけで英語になってしまったのであれば、何かしらうまくインストールされていない可能性があります。

Windows とのことなので、思いつく可能性としては WSL を使っている場合で、WSL の VS Code には Language Pack が入っているが Windows 側では無効になっている場合です。

まずはインストールされている拡張機能一覧を開いて Language Pack が有効になっているか確認してください。

Comment: VScodeで確認させていただきましたがインストールできていて有効になっていると思います。インストールできているのでアンインストールの表示になっていました。再起動(windowsのリロード？)してみましたが変化はありませんでした。

Comment: 再度再起動したら日本語になりました。

Comment: 理由はわかりませんが一応求めていた結果となりました。お世話になりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

コマンドパレットから `>Configure Display Language` (表示言語を構成する) コマンドを使用したとき
「日本語」ロケールを選択しましたか？

以前の [Japanese Language Pack for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-CEINTL.vscode-language-pack-ja) では無かったけど, 必要になった操作です

参考: (code.visualstudio.com) [Display Language](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales)

Comment: その操作もさせていただきました。選択後も変化がありません。